# C# Object.Equals() with multiple or conditions

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How can I use the Equals method, so that it checks if the user ID equals **any** of the IDs in someIDs? In this case, I want to get all the users where the ID is the same as the IDs in someIDs.

```
List<int> someIDs = someList.Select(x => x.id).ToList();
List<User> result = allUsers.Where(x => x.id.Equals(someIDs)).ToList();
```

This is what works, however it is hardcoded. I want it to be similar.

```
List<int> someIDs = someList.Select(x => x.id).ToList();
List<User> result = allUsers.Where(x => x.id.Equals(someIDs[0]) ||
                                        x.id.Equals(someIDs[1]) ||
                                        x.id.Equals(someIDs[2])
).ToList();
```

Comment: `x => someIDs.Contains(x.id)`

Comment: Don't be so quick to call `ToList()`. You can change the declaration of the first variable to `var`, remove the `ToList()`, and things will still work. Now you have _less code_ that does the same work in _less time_ and with _less memory use_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *not* override `Equals` to provide a method for checking the `id` matches a list. Instead use what is already provided on an array/list

```
var result = allUsers.Where(x => someIDs.Contains(x.id)).ToList();
```